# How to choose nginx version during rpm install

Tags: linux, nginx, centos7

According to [nginx.org](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#stable) instruction on how to install nginx by `.rpm`, it says that I should do the following.

open `nginx.repo`

```
$ vi /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo
```

paste the following content in it (for CentOs7)

```
[nginx]
name=nginx repo
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/7/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

then simply do `yum install nginx`

This works, but it installs the mainline version and not the stable one.  As of now I have `1.8.0`

```
[root@localhost ~]# nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.8.0
```

So, my question is, how do I install the stable version which is currently, at `v1.6.3` according to [nginx.org](http://nginx.org)

> 2015-04-07  nginx-1.6.3 stable and nginx-1.7.12 mainline versions have been released.

Comment: nginx version 1.8.0 is now stable version. see the link now 2015-04-21 

nginx-1.8.0 stable version has been released

Comment: Yep.  `nginx` follows a common method for version numbers: Even for stable, odd for mainline/feature testing. 1.8 is really just the stable release of the 1.7 line.

Comment: Thanks, I was in doubt as to how the stable version jumped from `1.6.3` to `1.8.0` in just two weeks. Normally, it takes way more than that for nginx.

Comment: It didn't; 1.8 has been in development (via the 1.7 branch) for a year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should take a look at what packages are available

```
yum --showduplicates list nginx
```

Looking at that repo, it appears that `nginx 1.6.3-1` is the version you want.

You can install the specific version by appending it to the package name with a dash:

```
yum install nginx-1.6.3-1
```

That said, nginx 1.8 has been released as stable.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone is searching for the installation of nginx 1.8, the following does not show nginx-1.8

```
yum --showduplicates list nginx
```

You can use a single command as below to download and install a rpm

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://nginx.org/packages/centos/7/x86_64/RPMS/nginx-1.8.0-1.el7.ngx.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

there is all [avliable RPMS packages](http://nginx.org/packages/centos/7/x86_64/RPMS/).

you can download it and then use rpm to install it.

`rpm -Uvh  nginx-*.rpm`